# Фильтр в Excel по множеству значений

Tags: база-данных, excel

Есть файл Excel с несколькими колонками.
Первый столбец - домены сайтов.

Также есть второй Excel файл, у которого также первый столблец содержит домены сайтов.

Необходимо в первом файле оставить только те домены, которые встречаются во втором файле.

При этом содержимое последующих столбцов (второго, третьего и т.д.) в первом файле не должно пропасть.

Подскажите, как это можно сделать быстро?

Через фильтр выбирать каждый домен по очереди будет очень долго.

Пробовал выбрать уникальные строки через инструмент `Данные > Фильтр > Дополнительно > Только уникальные записи`, предварительно вставив в первый столбец первого файла строки из второго файла, но не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Вам поможет функция СЧЁТЕСЛИ:

```
=СЧЁТЕСЛИ({сюда столбец в котором ищем};{сюда ссылку на искомый домен})
```

Применяете эту формулу для каждого домена. Получается столбец из цифровых значений. Потом просто фильтруете и выбираете не нули.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здравствуйте! Спасибо, но почему-то сортировка неверно сработала. Не могу понять, в чем может быть причина.

Comment: попробуйте перед сортировкой заморозить все расчитанные значения (скопировать их в другой столбец, но только как значения). Возможно они у Вас пересчитываются после скрытия части второго столбца.